# Function to manipulate array of unknown nested object and print all elements including key, key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to read through an array of nested objects with unknown key and values.

would like to create two set of arrays as an output one with all the elements and the next one is how they are related

code is as shown below

```
var data = {
   "device":{
      "name":"Device1",
      "config":{
         "interface":[
            {
               "Loopback":{
                  "name":"{loopback-intf}",
                  "description":{
                     "_tags":"merge",
                     "__text":"Loopback{loopback-intf}"
                  },
                  "ip":{
                     "address":{
                        "primary":{
                           "address":"{ip-address}",
                           "mask":"255.255.255.255"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "_xmlns":"urn:www",
               "_tags":"merge"
            },
            {
               "Loopback":{
                  "name":"{loopback-intf}",
                  "description":{
                     "_tags":"merge",
                     "__text":"Loopback{loopback-intf}"
                  },
                  "ip":{
                     "address":{
                        "primary":{
                           "address":"{ip-address}",
                           "mask":"255.255.255.255"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "_xmlns":"http://ww.com/test/xx-xr",
               "_tags":"merge"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
};


function iter(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof(obj[key]) == 'object') {
      iter(obj[key]);
    } else {
      alert("Key: " + key + " Values: " + obj[key]);
    }
  }
}

//alert(JSON.stringify(iter(data)));
//console.log(iter(data));
iter(data);
```

The above just returns elements with key value pair but i need all the elements so that i can push them to first array one by one

```
device
name:Device1
config
interface
loopback
name:loopback-inf
description
tags:merge
_text:Loopback{loopback-intf}
ip
address
primary
address:"ip-address"
mask:255.255.255.255
_xmlns:urn:ios
_tags:merge and so on ....
```

2. This array should have relation ship mapping for the each of elements that were pushed in the first array

I think i can manage the second part if i figure out how can i push all the elements without knowing the key and value.

Comment: I am having difficulties in managing the second part. any recommendations here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, try this

```js
var data = {
  "device": {
    "name": "Device1",
    "config": {
      "interface": [{
        "Loopback": {
          "name": "{loopback-intf}",
          "description": {
            "_tags": "merge",
            "__text": "Loopback{loopback-intf}"
          },
          "ip": {
            "address": {
              "primary": {
                "address": "{ip-address}",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "_xmlns": "urn:www",
        "_tags": "merge"
      }, {
        "Loopback": {
          "name": "{loopback-intf}",
          "description": {
            "_tags": "merge",
            "__text": "Loopback{loopback-intf}"
          },
          "ip": {
            "address": {
              "primary": {
                "address": "{ip-address}",
                "mask": "255.255.255.255"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "_xmlns": "http://ww.com/test/xx-xr",
        "_tags": "merge"
      }]
    }
  }
};

function iter(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof(obj[key]) == 'object') {
      if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
        console.log(key);
      }
      iter(obj[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key + " : " + obj[key]);
    }
  }
}

iter(data);
```

You need to print the key if the type of value is object but not Array.